# A problem is occured in running the code in python

Tags: image, registration, medical

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [16, 2, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 1024, 1, 512, 512] to have 2 channels, but got 1024 channels instead
This error is occured.

```
def forward(self, fixed, moving):
    concat_image = torch.cat((fixed, moving), dim=1)  # 2 x 512 x 512
    x1 = self.conv1(concat_image)  # 16 x 256 x 256
    x2 = self.conv2(x1)  # 32 x 128 x 128
    x3 = self.conv3(x2)  # 1 x 64 x 64 x 64
    x3_1 = self.conv3_1(x3)  # 64 x 64 x 64
    x4 = self.conv4(x3_1)  # 128 x 32 x 32
    x4_1 = self.conv4_1(x4)  # 128 x 32 x 32
    x5 = self.conv5(x4_1)  # 256 x 16 x 16
    x5_1 = self.conv5_1(x5)  # 256 x 16 x 16
    x6 = self.conv6(x5_1)  # 512 x 8 x 8
    x6_1 = self.conv6_1(x6)  # 512 x 8 x 8

    pred6 = self.pred6(x6_1)  # 2 x 8 x 8
    upsamp6to5 = self.upsamp6to5(pred6)  # 2 x 16 x 16
    deconv5 = self.deconv5(x6_1)  # 256 x 16 x 16
    concat5 = torch.cat([x5_1, deconv5, upsamp6to5], dim=1)  # 514 x 16 x 16

    pred5 = self.pred5(concat5)  # 2 x 16 x 16
    upsamp5to4 = self.upsamp5to4(pred5)  # 2 x 32 x 32
    deconv4 = self.deconv4(concat5)  # 2 x 32 x 32
    concat4 = torch.cat([x4_1, deconv4, upsamp5to4], dim=1)  # 258 x 32 x 32

    pred4 = self.pred4(concat4)  # 2 x 32 x 32
    upsamp4to3 = self.upsamp4to3(pred4)  # 2 x 64 x 64
    deconv3 = self.deconv3(concat4)  # 64 x 64 x 64
    concat3 = torch.cat([x3_1, deconv3, upsamp4to3], dim=1)  # 130 x 64 x 64

    pred3 = self.pred3(concat3)  # 2 x 63 x 64
    upsamp3to2 = self.upsamp3to2(pred3)  # 2 x 128 x 128
    deconv2 = self.deconv2(concat3)  # 32 x 128 x 128
    concat2 = torch.cat([x2, deconv2, upsamp3to2], dim=1)  # 66 x 128 x 128

    pred2 = self.pred2(concat2)  # 2 x 128 x 128
    upsamp2to1 = self.upsamp2to1(pred2)  # 2 x 256 x 256
    deconv1 = self.deconv1(concat2)  # 16 x 256 x 256
    concat1 = torch.cat([x1, deconv1, upsamp2to1], dim=1)  # 34 x 256 x 256

    pred0 = self.pred0(concat1)  # 2 x 512 x 512

    return pred0 * 20 * self.flow_multiplier
```

Comment: I see lots of lines of uncommented code, that is not runnable and has no `import` statements - so not an [mcve]. Also no discussion of what you are trying to do or where the error occurs. If you want folk to help you, consider making it easy for them to do so.